# Two loggers with different appenders

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

Let's say I have two loggers configured in log4j.xml like this:

```
<logger name="syslog-logger">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="syslog" />
</logger>

<logger name="kafka-logger">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="KafkaStream"/>
</logger>
```

how can I use slf4j to get both of those? Like this:

```
private final Logger sysLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("syslog-logger");
private final Logger kafkaLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("kafka-logger");
```

Comment: Can you please specify what you intend to do after you obtain both loggers? What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in doing it the way you want it, because you can only get one logger per instance. 
What you could do is, creating another logger which combines your two loggers and adds both appenders:

```
<logger name="kafka-syslog-logger">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="syslog" />
    <appender-ref ref="KafkaStream"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: great but how I can specify where to send my message (syslog or kafka)?

Comment: You simply cant. If you want to specify that, you'd have to use two different loggers or create a method where you specify, to which output you want to send it

Comment: Oh, that's fine. I can specify output in method but how I would do that?

Comment: Well I guess I can just use CRITICAL for kafka and be done with it

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look into the documentation, because there are many ways to configure your loggers.